# Disable Flurry Xcode console logging

Tags: ios, xcode, flurry, flurry-analytics

With the latest Flurry iOS SDK, 8.0.2, I keep seeing this in the Xcode console. How do I disable this logging?

```
FlurrySession: Attempting to record Event eventName[xxxx] with parameters[xxxx]
FlurrySession: Event count for eventName[xxxx] updated to count[1]
FlurrySession: Recording event eventName[xxxx] with parameters[(null)] complete
```

There's more verbose logging

```
FlurryDataSenderBase: networkStatusChanged to  reachable
FlurryDataSenderBase: networkStatusChanged to  reachable
FlurryDataSender: Not sent blocks count [3]
FlurrySession: networkStatusChanged to  reachable
FlurryPulseReportSender: -[FlurryPulseCBReportSender retransmitNotSentBlocks], Not sent blocks count [0]
FlurrySession: networkStatusChanged to  reachable

Flurry: HTTP connection delegate received response[<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x61800022f7a0> { URL: https://data.flurry.com/aas.do } { status code: 200, headers {

"Content-Length" = 198;
"Content-Type" = "application/octet-stream";
Date = "Sat, 06 May 2017 19:07:01 GMT";
Server = nginx;
} }]

FlurryDataSender: async http response code: 200, id [89610511-B2AF-4D50-B2EF-B45E7EDFC357]

+[FlurryGlobalVariableStorage getPersistentFilePath:]: /Users/xxxxxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/xxxxxxx-8D00-4012ABC56E4A/data/Containers/Data/Application/xxxxxxxxF5D-848F-31412106EFA5/Library/Application Support/FlurryFiles/.flurryCkData427987809_198.archive
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can disable logs by calling `setLogLevel:` selector of Flurry.h

```
[Flurry setLogLevel:FlurryLogLevelNone];
```

Swift.

```
Flurry.setLogLevel(FlurryLogLevelNone)
```

Comment: Thanks, I missed that.

Comment: Strange, but it doesn't help to me

Comment: The same, still writes tons of boilerplate to console

Answer (score 0):

Modern SDK (12.1.1), Swift 5:

```
Flurry.set(logLevel: .none)
```

or

```
Flurry.set(logLevel: .criticalOnly)
```

if you want to see criticals. But IMHO it's still a lot of spam in criticalOnly level so I turn it completely off after testing setup